# can I use a laptop DVD-ROM drive in a bare bones system the make of the system Shuttle XS35

Tags: installation, dvd

I have a Shuttle XS35 which i want to use to build a system, I have a dvd drive, memory, and hard drive with Windows Vista that i have from a Dell Inspiron 1437, which i want to use - can i use these parts with the Shuttle?

Answer (score 1):

quick answer is, Maybe.

Longer answer is most laptop DVD drives use a different physical interface than the sata or pata interface most systems use - Looking at the system, its designed to use a slimline CD rom drive, so that should be a non issue, and a 2.5inch drive (tho, i'd assume it'd need to be SATA).

I'm fairly certain ram should be fine as well - it accepts SODIMM ram - which is what laptops use

I got most of the information from [here](http://global.shuttle.com/product_detail_spec.jsp?PI=1423) - which should be of use in terms of referencing what would work.

I'd also note that windows is linked to the system its on, so a reinstall may be needed.